# How to change image into data.frame

Tags: python, dataframe, image

Can I have help turning this image into a dataframe with python code, please?
I'm sorry, I don't know where to start.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert or extract a table from an image using Tesseract?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61418907/how-to-convert-or-extract-a-table-from-an-image-using-tesseract)

Answer (score 0):

open a .csv file, put the data into this file and load it as a dataframe

```
pd.read_csv('data.csv')
```

another way is to split this image into small pieces and each number try to predict by a machine learning model, like for the MNIST dataset [(Kaggle)](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/hojjatk/mnist-dataset)